# Is there a built-in test for whether a string (or handle) refers to a script?

Tags: matlab

The function below is a homegrown hack to detect whether its argument refers to a script or not

```
function yesno = is_script(string_or_handle)
    try
        nargin(string_or_handle);
        yesno = false;
    catch me
        if ~strcmp(me.identifier, 'MATLAB:nargin:isScript')
            rethrow(me);
        end
        yesno = true;
    end
end
```

Such hacks are hard to maintain.  (This one will break, for example, whenever MathWorks decides to change the class of exception identifier that `nargin` throws when it gets a script as input.)

Does MATLAB already have a built-in function to do this?

Comment: I understand you want to differentiate scripts _from functions_. Does your approach differentiate between a script and a function that takes no inputs?

Comment: What about `run(which(string_or_handle));` which will error if it is not a standalone script file?

Comment: @AndrasDeak True ...

Comment: @LuisMendo: yes, since the `nargin` expression evaluates without error when its argument is *any* function, irrespective of the number of arguments, and therefore in that case `yesno` will be set to `false`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could modify your hack to be less prune to future "breaking" by running the `try-catch` block only for function handles. In this case you would know that *if* an error if thrown, then the input handle is a script (no need to investigate error details; hence no sensitivity to exception identifiers).

```
function yesno = is_script(string_or_handle)
    yesno = false;
    if isa(string_or_handle,'function_handle') || ... 
        exist(string_or_handle,'file') == 2
        try
            nargin(string_or_handle);
        catch me
            yesno = true;
        end  
    end
end
```

Comment: `isa(string_or_handle,'function_handle')` would also do.

Comment: @AndrasDeak The advantage here is that we know that the `nargin` will only break for scripts, so we needn't include the exception identifier (that OP fear will possibly break in future releases).

Comment: @AndrasDeak As a final update I had to add the check vs function handles as `exist(..)` can't take function handles as arguments (takes argument type string). So now, given that input `string_or_handle` is a string or handle, this should work. (Also: I'll remove my comments above now to clean up. Thanks for feedback!)

Comment: Nice use of short-circuiting:) Thanks for the ping, I cleaned up as well.

Answer (score 1):

Loren from MathWorks has a [blog article](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/08/26/what-kind-of-matlab-file-is-this/) about exactly this question from back in 2013.

She uses the same method as you do in your question - and for what it's worth, the message identifier is the same and hasn't changed in at least three years (in fact it's a lot longer than that), so I think you can stop worrying about your solution.

Usefully, Loren also adds an extra piece of functionality to distinguish class files, as well as functions and scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!  (Now I'm kind of proud of my little hack.)